# Highcharts graph not updated on iPad

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working on a Highcharts graph with live data retrieved from a server.
The following is based on an example supplied by Highcharts, which works fine on a Windows system with Chrome. But when viewing the same on an iPad with Chrome (or Safari), the graph is not being updated. So adding points from within the posting.done function does not reach the series data.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg,
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var posting = $.post( "smartmeter", function( data ) {});
                        posting.done(function( data ) {
                            var values = data.split(';');
                            y = parseInt(values[2]);
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(); // current time
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        });

                    }, 1000);
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Any errors in JS? Is "done" called?

Comment: In Chrome in Windows I can check for JS errors (no errors). But on an iPad I don't have this functionality (unfortunately). I however checked whether "done"  is called. In Windows it is called (as expected), but in iOS it is not. So it is not a Highcharts issue. With this information I will dig deeper. Thanks for that!

Comment: Changed from a POST request to a GET request (which also makes more sense). Now function .done is called and data added correctly to the graphs, also on iOS.